# Constructors in Kotlin

Tags: android, constructor, kotlin

I am learning `Kotlin` from official docs, I created one `class` like below where I created one `constructor` which has two `parameters`. Body of `constructor` is in `init` block.

```
class Person(name: String, surname: String) {
    init {
        Log.d("App", "Hello");
    }
}
```

Well, I want to create one more `constructor` which will take one `parameter` in a `constructor`. What is the way to do in `Kotlin`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Well `init` is not body of constructor. It is called after primary constructor with the context of primary constructor.

As given in Official documentation:

> The primary constructor cannot contain any code. Initialization code can be placed in initializer blocks, which are prefixed with the init keyword:

```
class Customer(name: String) {
    init {
        logger.info("Customer initialized with value ${name}")
    }
}
```

> Note that parameters of the primary constructor can be used in the initializer blocks. They can also be used in property initializers declared in the class body:

```
class Customer(name: String) {
    val customerKey = name.toUpperCase()
}
```

> In fact, for declaring properties and initializing them from the primary constructor, Kotlin has a concise syntax:

```
class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, var age: Int) {
    // ...
}
```

---

As per your question you can add a constructor to accept one parameter like following:

```
class Person(name: String, surname: String) {

    constructor(name: String) : this(name, "") {
        // constructor body
    }

    init {
        Log.d("App", "Hello");
    }
}
```

But it doesn't look right as we are unnecessary passing second argument empty string. So we can order constructor like following:

```
class Person(name: String) {

    constructor(name: String, surname: String) : this(name) {
        // constructor body
    }

    init {
        Log.d("App", "Hello");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does `this(name)` calls primary constructor ? If so can we log to check ?

Comment: `this()` is used to call constructor, its parameter signature defines which constructor to call.

Comment: Yep correct. Can we check is it calling primary constructor or not by logging ?

Comment: As given in documentation primary constructor does not have body, but you can put that code in `init` block, it should do the trick.

Comment: One argument on this(name),  if we consider the constructor as a special method or func, is not this(name) a return type?

Comment: Return type for what? Constructors does not return any value.@FarruhHabibullaev

Answer (score 5):

First way with empty values

```
// (name: String, surname: String)  default constructor signature
class Person(name: String, surname: String) {

    // init block , represents the body of default constructor 
    init {
        Log.d("primary", "Hello");
    }

    // secondary constructor 
    // this(name,"") call to default constructor
    constructor(name : String):this(name,""){
        Log.d("secondary", "Hello");
    }
}
```

why `this(name,"")`

> If the class has a primary constructor, each secondary constructor
>   needs to delegate to the primary constructor, either directly or
>   indirectly through another secondary constructor(s). Delegation to
>   another constructor of the same class is done using the this keyword:

or

kotlin won't allow to use `null` like `this(name,null)` so use `?` to represent `null` values with type, `surname: String?`

```
class Person(name: String, surname: String?) {

    init {
        Log.d("primary", "Hello");
    }

    constructor(name : String):this(name,null){
        Log.d("secondary", "Hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the class use `constructor` keyword to create secondary constructor. Like :

```
class Person(name: String, surname: String) {
    init {
        Log.d("App", "Hello");
    }
    constructor(id: Int) {

    }
}
```

For more info check [Secondary Constructors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html)

**EDIT:**

*Rule :* If the class has a primary constructor, each secondary constructor needs to delegate to the primary constructor, either directly or indirectly through another secondary constructor(s). Delegation to another constructor of the same class is done using the this keyword.

```
class Person(val name: String) {
    constructor(name: String, parent: Person) : this(name) {
        parent.children.add(this)
    }
}
```

So when you call secondary constructor, it calls primary constructor to initialize name and after that you do your stuff in secondary constructor. In example above the name is initialized by calling primary constructor.

Comment: I have this code `class Person(name: String, surname: String) {
    init {
        Log.d("Hello", "Hello $name $surname");
    }

    constructor(name: String) {

    }
}` after adding secondary constructor, Android Studio hinting me `Error:(10, 5) Primary constructor call expected`

Comment: This is because, you will have to call the primary constructor using the this keyword. Writing an answer soon to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

Secondary Constructors

The class can also declare secondary constructors, which are prefixed with constructor:

```
class Person {
    constructor(parent: Person) {
        parent.children.add(this)
    } }
```

If the class has a primary constructor, each secondary constructor needs to delegate to the primary constructor, either directly or indirectly through another secondary constructor(s). Delegation to another constructor of the same class is done using the this keyword:

```
class Person(val name: String) {
    constructor(name: String, parent: Person) : this(name) {
        parent.children.add(this)
    } }
```

see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html  Secondary Constructors part

Answer (score 1):

This is how you create another constructor.

```
class Person(name: String, surname: String) {
    init {
        Log.d("App", "Hello");
    }
 constructor(id: Int) : this("example name", "example surname") {

}
}
```

Always remember that, the secondary constructor will have to reference the primary constructor and it's parameters using the this keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable 'internal' and then you can add multiple constructors inside single class like below.

```
class AuthModel {
var code: String? = null

internal constructor(code: String?) {
    this.code = code
}

internal constructor() {}
}
```